# Are Zookas and Riflemen Equivalent?

Tags: boom-beach

In Boom Beach, I'm trying to figure out the balancing between Zookas and Riflemen. Yes, Zookas are substantially higher in damage, but bear with me:

Riflemen stats (level 12):

- Health: 295
- DPS: 71
- Size: 1

Zooka stats (level 12):

- Health: 126
- DPS: 228
- Size: 2

So, by this logic, in a single attack with 6 barges of size 14, you can have 84 riflemen (at 5954 aggregate DPS, and 24780 total hit points), or 42 zookas (at 9576 aggregate DPS, but only 5292 total hit points).

Another way to think about it is that every rifleman can get hit essentially twice (vs once for a a Zooka), so they can shoot twice as many times.

Comment: The stats don't factor "range", which is kind of a big deal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short version:
Zookas are better for Operations in Task Forces.
Riflemen are better on PVP/NPC bases.
If you choose either side (all Zookas or all Rifleman): The more damage you take, the more the Riflemen will dominate over Zookas, since they will "last" longer.

Here are some links about that topic. :)

- http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/587549-All-Zooka-vs-all-Rifleman?p=4095293#post4095293
- http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/562198-Ideal-ratio-zooka-infantry-when-facing-many-one-shot-kill-defense

Comment: This is really interesting, but still feels wrong. The problem with his strategy is you need the heavies (or something) in front to absorb targeting from the rockets and/or mortars, even with one-shot defense. Thanks though!

Comment: @aronchick: No, all Zookas means "only Zookas", so no heavies involved. :) You just need to be sure that splash-damage defensives are taken out/shocked while you attack. You compensate casualties with the big mass of units you bring on the battlefield. :)

Answer (score 2):

You missed out one crucial stat according to me, *Range*. Range of rifleman is *Medium* whereas that of zooka is *Long*.

So if you couple this troop with Heavy, he will absorb all damage until he dies(except for defenses with blind spot like rocket launcher, mortar). So your zookas will be protected and will be dealing good damage from a safe spot behind.

So, zookas and riflemen are not equivalent,even though their damage stats are almost near(which is not that close either).

Answer (score 0):

The DPS of any troop shows Damage per **Second**. You missed another point *"Damage per **shot**"*. 228 DPS of lvl 12 Zookas is Damage per **second**. While her Damage per shot is 228 x 2 = 456. So your last assumption that Riflemen can shoot twice than Zookas is wrong.

> Total damage from two Riflemen for two seconds
>   = DPSecond x 2 (units) x 2 (shots)
>   = 71 x 2 x 2 = **284**
>
> Total damage from one Zooka fro two seconds
>   = DPSecond x 1 (units) x 2 (shots)
>   = 228 x 1 x 2 = **456**